# SQL Server tables with same column but non matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables with the same columns, but non matching records.

Table 1

```
ID
----
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table 2

```
ID
-----
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
6
7
8
9
10
```

I need to pull the `NOT NULL` records as given below.

Desired output:

```
ID   ID
--------
1     6
2     7
3     8
4     9
5     10
```

Comment: How are the related? Why should ID 1 from Table 1 be on the same row with ID 6 from Table 2? Is it just row number?

Comment: Tag the only version that you are going to run the query, as because `2005` doesn't supports analytical functionality.

Answer (score 1):

One method is aggregation:

```
select max(id1) as id1, max(id2) as id2
from ((select t1.id as id1, null as id2 row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select null as id1, t2.id row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
       from t2
       where t2.id is not null
      ) 
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Note:  This includes *all* ids, even if one table is larger than the other.  If you only want rows where both ids are populated, `join` is another method:

```
select t1.id as id1, t2.id as  as id2
from (select t1.id as id1, null as id2 row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     (select null as id1, t2.id row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t2
      where t2.id is not null
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```